# Javascript alert not working for first array value in php

Tags: php, html

I am implementing clothing shopping website and currently i am working on add to cart. on every cloth item there is add to cart button through which item is added to cart. i am using session array for storing values in cart. i am using javascript alert to show message "Item added to cart" when add to cart button is clicked. i am facing problem that when i click add to cart button first time it doesn't show any message but it works perfectly for 2nd and all other time. only on first click it shows nothing.

**Code:**

```
<?php
session_start();
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login");
if (isset($_POST["add_to_cart"])) {
  if (isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {

    $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], "item_id");
    if (!in_array($_GET["id"], $item_array_id)) {
      $count = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
      $item_array = array(
        'item_id' => $_GET["id"],
        'item_description' => $_POST["dress_description"],
        'item_price' => $_POST["price"],
        'item_quantity' => $_POST["dress_quantity"],
        'item_gender' => $_POST["gender_name"]
      );

      $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$count] = $item_array;
      echo '<script>alert("Item Added to Cart")</script>';
      echo '<script>window.location="portfolionew.php"</script>';
    } else {
      echo '<script>alert("Item Already Added")</script>';
      echo '<script>window.location="portfolionew.php"</script>';
    }
  } else {
    $item_array = array(
      'item_id' => $_GET["id"],
      'item_description' => $_POST["dress_description"],
      'item_price' => $_POST["price"],
      'item_quantity' => $_POST["dress_quantity"],
      'item_gender' => $_POST["gender_name"]
    );
    $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][0] = $item_array;
    echo '<script>alert("Item Added to Cart")</script>';
    echo '<script>window.location="portfolionew.php"</script>';
  }
}
?>


// and this is cart button:
<input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" class="fa fa-shopping-cart" value="Cart">
```

Comment: Please post your javascript as well!

Comment: just using javascript alert you can see where i am echoing javascript alert

Comment: maybe session `isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])` is not set and it's not getting inside `if` condition

Comment: Your session is setting on first redirect. i.e. `else` is being executed on first time. 2nd time it goes to `if`.

Comment: Write Item added alert in `else` part of `if (isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {`. Because, first time, there is no session set for items.

Comment: can you please edit this code? @ BCoder

Comment: @Nana Partykar now thanks it is working perfectly :)

Comment: @ShoaibSharoon Please check the edits.

Comment: Please don't edit your answers into the question ...

Comment: @Nana Partykar can you anwser this question please https://stackoverflow.com/q/45713744/8380733

Comment: @ShoaibSharoon: Answered.

Answer (score 1):

Here issue is for first time your not added code to alert.
Change code from

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login");
    if (isset($_POST["add_to_cart"])) {
      if (isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {

        $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], "item_id");
        if (!in_array($_GET["id"], $item_array_id)) {
          $count = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
          $item_array = array(
            'item_id' => $_GET["id"],
            'item_description' => $_POST["dress_description"],
            'item_price' => $_POST["price"],
            'item_quantity' => $_POST["dress_quantity"],
            'item_gender' => $_POST["gender_name"]
          );

          $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$count] = $item_array;
          echo '<script>alert("Item Added to Cart")</script>';
          echo '<script>window.location="portfolionew.php"</script>';
        } else {
          echo '<script>alert("Item Already Added")</script>';
          echo '<script>window.location="portfolionew.php"</script>';
        }
      } else {
        $item_array = array(
          'item_id' => $_GET["id"],
          'item_description' => $_POST["dress_description"],
          'item_price' => $_POST["price"],
          'item_quantity' => $_POST["dress_quantity"],
          'item_gender' => $_POST["gender_name"]
        );
        $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][0] = $item_array;
      }
    }
    ?>
```

to

```
<?php
session_start();
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login");
if (isset($_POST["add_to_cart"])) {
  if (isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {

    $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], "item_id");
    if (!in_array($_GET["id"], $item_array_id)) {
      $count = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
      $item_array = array(
        'item_id' => $_GET["id"],
        'item_description' => $_POST["dress_description"],
        'item_price' => $_POST["price"],
        'item_quantity' => $_POST["dress_quantity"],
        'item_gender' => $_POST["gender_name"]
      );

      $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$count] = $item_array;
      echo '<script>alert("Item Added to Cart")</script>';
      echo '<script>window.location="portfolionew.php"</script>';
    } else {
      echo '<script>alert("Item Already Added")</script>';
      echo '<script>window.location="portfolionew.php"</script>';
    }
  } else {
    $item_array = array(
      'item_id' => $_GET["id"],
      'item_description' => $_POST["dress_description"],
      'item_price' => $_POST["price"],
      'item_quantity' => $_POST["dress_quantity"],
      'item_gender' => $_POST["gender_name"]
    );
    $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][0] = $item_array;

    /***************** add ********************/
    echo '<script>alert("Item Added to Cart")</script>';
    echo '<script>window.location="portfolionew.php"</script>';

  }
}
?>
```

Comment: I think this could be a better answer if you post the additional code separate and explain how / why this additional code should used.